# Change the toc entry of the appendix to same size as part

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I would like to change the toc entry generated by the package `appendix` (and not the entries of the appendix chapters) so it has the same size as a "Part" in the document. How could I proceed ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

% Packages that may have an impact but probably not.
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `Appendix 1` should look like a part? Or just the `Appendix` toc entry?

Comment: The appendix toc entry. The appendices can stay the way they are. Sorry for the imprecision.

Comment: No worries. See my possible solution, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\begin{appendices}` calls basically `\appendixpage` which in turn uses `\addappheadtoc`, which lately sets the `\addcontentsline` or `\addtocontents`, depending on `hyperref` usage, both with `chapter` as entry level

The easiest way is to patch `\addappheadtotoc` with and replacing `chapter` with `part`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

% Packages that may have an impact but probably not.
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
%%%%%

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  {chapter}%
}{%
  {part}%
}{\typeout{success}}{}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter 1}


\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple, efficient. I will let you know though if my thesis does not like this code, but I cannot see any reason why. Thanks a lot indeed !

Comment: @HcN: Yes, come back to it, if there are some problems with a larger file.